# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n3^n}{2n+1}z^{2n+1}$ for $|z|= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have shown that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n3^n}{2n+1}z^{2n+1}$$
converges for $|z|<\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$. Can anyone help me to study the convergence for $|z|= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$?

Comment: You can try the Dirichlet test. The answer is that, when $|z| = 1/\sqrt{3}$, the series converges conditionally when $z \neq \pm i/\sqrt{3}$ and diverges when $z = \pm i/\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a complex or a real series, i.e. by $|z| = \sqrt{3}/3$  do you mean a circle in the complex plane or just $\pm\sqrt{3}/3$? The latter case is very simple (alternating series test) so I'm assuming that it it's the former case that applies here?! Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use the series
$$
\arctan(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
$$
Using [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Dirichlet.27s_test), we get that, except for $z=\pm i\frac{\sqrt3}3$, the series converges. Using [Abel's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_theorem), we get that for $z=\frac{\sqrt3}3e^{i\theta}$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n3^n}{2n+1}\left(\frac{\sqrt3}3e^{i\theta}\right)^{2n+1}
&=\frac{\sqrt3}3\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{e^{i\theta(2n+1)}}{2n+1}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt3}3\left(\arctan\left(e^{i\theta}\right)-1\right)\\
&=\frac{\sqrt3}3\left(\frac i2\log\left(\frac{i+e^{i\theta}}{i-e^{i\theta}}\right)-1\right)
\end{align}
$$
which only blows up when $e^{i\theta}=\pm i$.

---

For $z=\pm i\frac{\sqrt3}3$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n3^n}{2n+1}\left(\pm i\frac{\sqrt3}3\right)^{2n+1}
&=\pm i\frac{\sqrt3}3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n+1}
\end{align}
$$
which diverges by comparison to the Harmonic Series.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Notice:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n3^n}{2n+1}z^{2n+1}=\frac{\sqrt{3}\arctan(z\sqrt{3})-3z}{3}\space\space,\text{when}\space\left|z\right|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

---

So if $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n3^n}{2n+1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^{2n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{3}(1+2n)}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{3}(1+2n)}=$$
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{2(-1)^m\Phi\left(-1,1,m+\frac{3}{2}\right)+\pi-4}{4\sqrt{3}}=$$
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^m\Phi\left(-1,1,m+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2\sqrt{3}}+\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=$$
$$\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^m\Phi\left(-1,1,m+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2\sqrt{3}}=$$
$$\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\lim_{m\to\infty}(-1)^m\Phi\left(-1,1,m+\frac{3}{2}\right)=$$
$$\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\cdot0=$$
$$\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+0=$$
$$\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=$$
$$\frac{\pi-4}{4\sqrt{3}}$$